# Send data from controller to js function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have controller:

```
function NameController($scope){
        $scope.data = {
            name: 'Alex',
        }
    }
```

and HTML

```
    <div ng-controller="NameController">
        <a href="#" onclick="alert( {{data.name}} );"> ClickMe </a>
    </div>
```

Why it doesn't work and how make it works?
Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `alert` in the view, it's actually looking for `$scope.alert`, which is undefined.  You can create an `alert` function in the controller that will call the javascript `alert` function:

```
$scope.alert = function(data){
   alert(data);
};
```

You should also use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="alert(data.name)"> ClickMe </a>
```

`ng-click` takes an angular expression.  If you use `onclick`, javascript (not angular) attempts to handle the click event, and it doesn't understand what `{{data.name}}` is.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xq187kDTCAfuUOvGxPB6?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert( '{{data.name}}' );"> ClickMe </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-click AngularJs Directive

so your HTML should be like:

```
<div ng-controller="NameController">
    <a href="#" ng-click="alert( {{data.name}} );"> ClickMe </a>
</div>
```

and in controller you have to define alert function like

```
 function NameController($scope){
    $scope.alert = function(name) {
        alert(name);
    }
 }
```